# How can I displayName from multiple accounts?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I created my account with firebase auth.

I can now keep the displayName, but if I post a message displaying the name of the current account when i change my account The name will also change.

What method should I use to retrieve the old displayName value that I have posted in another account?

But even the name displayed in the app has changed. But the firestore still shows the name of the account that posted this message.

**This is my get displayName code**.

```
FirebaseUser currentUser;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Text("${currentUser.displayName}")}
```

**Update disPlayName**

```
Future _register() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailController.text,
      password: _passwordController.text,
    ))
        .user;
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          this.context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
    FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    var userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
    userUpdateInfo.displayName = _nameController.text;
    await currentUser.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
    await currentUser.reload();
  }
```

**Update!!**

I solved this way And it works!!

```
final DocumentSnapshot data;
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Text(widget.data['displayName'])}
```

Comment: Can you pls explain a little bit more what your problem is and show more code you use to change the `displayName`.

Comment: In comparison, it's like Facebook where each account has a displayName. own And when you see another account's post, it will show displayName. of other accounts, but for me the displayName changes with the current account. do you understand?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to realtime state of your currentUser you would need to use the [authStateCanges](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state) listener:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      // SYNC your user to firestore
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

With that you will always have the correct `displayName`. If you just get the `FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();` it won't be always up to date if you change the `displayName` while your app is running.

If you are syncing the `auth` data to [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) I can recommend to do this also in that listener. That way you don't vory how to sync the `auth` data while changing it. The listener will do it automatically if the `auth` data changes.

When you save the `displayName` in some posts the user creates you can create a cloud function to sync the old name with the new one.

I hope all this help you understand the `auth` state in Firebase and how to make such syncs in the app state and database.